# Going from Frankfurt Airport to Mainz by train - DBahn Strike?

Tags: trains, germany, airport-transfer, event-based-effects, fra

I need to go from Frankfurt Airport to Mainz this Saturday and I saw on the news that the German Rail is on strike. Are there going to be any trains this Saturday that connect Frankfurt Airport to Mainz? If so which Services are these?

If there's no train at all, is there any Bus/subway that I could take instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the strike there is restricted timetable - so you maybe have to wait longer, but you can get to Mainz by train. Take S8 or RB/RE to Mainz Main Station (Mainz Hauptbahnhof).
According to [Deutsche Bahn](http://www.bahn.de/blitz/view/hessen/uebersicht.shtml) S8 will run every hour.

Another option would be to get a ride. Check [blablacar.de standard link from the city](https://www.blablacar.de/mitfahren/frankfurt-am-main/mainz/) 
or [better this one, from the airport](https://www.blablacar.de/search?fn=Frankfurt%20Flughafen%2C%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main&fcc=DE&tn=Mainz&tcc=DE#comuto_cmkt=DE_CARPOOLING_MFG-Redirect) there are few rides from Frankfurt Airport to Mainz.